# removing a list of columns from a data.frame using subset

Tags: r, dataframe

I often need to remove lists of columns from a data.frame.

I usually do this:

```
to.remove <- c("hp","drat","wt","qsec")
mtcars[,-which(names(mtcars) %in% to.remove)]
```

which works fine.

But I'd like to be able to do this in a cleaner way using `subset`. But it seems to be attaching the data.frame and then accessing the column names as variables rather than strings.

For instance this is what I would like to be able to do:

```
subset(mtcars,select=-to.remove)
```

Is there a way to force `subset` to use a vectors of strings in the `select` statement? Or is there another better alternative?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I would probably do this like so:

```
to.remove <- c("hp","drat","wt","qsec")
`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
subset(mtcars,select = names(mtcars) %ni% to.remove)
```

(I use `%ni%` a lot, so I have it built into my .Rprofile already.)

Comment: Nice use of a binary operator created with negate +1

Comment: @TylerRinker I can't recall anymore where I picked that function up from. Must have been either SO or r-help.

Comment: Very cool to learn about Negate.  I rarely use things in `funprog` and this is a great use for it.

Comment: +1, `Negate` looks like quite a useful hidden gem, as does `%ni%`. And your next task is to cut down the mightiest tree in the forest with... a herring!

Comment: For completeness you can also use the `!` operator just like: `mtcars[,!(names(mtcars) %in% to.remove)]`

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly use select, but you've got to pass in names, not characters. So this will work:

```
subset( mtcars, select = -c(hp, drat, wt, qsec) )
```

Comment: I would like to create a vector of names and send into select. but that doesn't work: