# R Not in subset

Tags: r, subset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standard way to remove multiple elements from a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494848/standard-way-to-remove-multiple-elements-from-a-dataframe)

I know in R that if you are searching for a subset of another group or matching based on id you'd use something like

```
subset(df1, df1$id %in% idNums1)
```

My question is how to do the opposite or choose items NOT matching a vector of ids.

I tried using `!` but get the error message

```
subset(df1, df1$id !%in% idNums1)
```

I think my backup is to do sometime like this:

```
matches <- subset(df1, df1$id %in% idNums1)
nonMatches <- df1[(-matches[,1]),]
```

but I'm hoping there's something a bit more efficient.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494848/standard-way-to-remove-multiple-elements-from-a-dataframe

Comment: Or equivalently to Chase's version, my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9846035/324364).

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The expression `df1$id %in% idNums1` produces a logical vector.  To negate it, you need to negate the whole vector:

```
!(df1$id %in% idNums1)
```

Comment: Remember the extra `()` with if statements. `if (!(something)) { print "not something"}`

Comment: The brackets being inconvenient when there are multiple nesting, I have found defining a ``not-in`` operator quite helpful. There are several suggestions on how to do that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831794/opposite-of-in