# R data.table i = MYVAR != %like% "something|somethingelse|somethingmore",

Tags: r, data.table

I have a general form for a data.table query where I can subset my data to only look at values that match the %like% statement, it looks like

```
DT[Var %like% "x|y|z", .N,]
```

And for the general operators for excluding values

```
i = x != "somevalue",
```

How can I combine these to ignore values that sound %like% some value and only return a set that don't match these requests.

The context here is a large database of customer data and trying to remove unwanted data so this list is much smaller than the list I am interested in.

Comment: Could you show your definition for `%like%`?

Comment: In R, you can generally build compound conditions in the usual ways, like `(cond1) & (!cond2)`; and this also works in `i`...

Comment: I've removed the actual char values but it looks like this `DT[Var != %like% "valuex|orthis|orthistoo", .N,]`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize that %like% was defined in the data.table package. I think you are looking for `DT[!(var %like% 'expr')]`?

Comment: Cheers @Frank Thanks! that did the trick. Should look like `DT[!(Var %like% "valuex|orthis|orthistoo"), .N,]`

Comment: Great! I guess I'll write that as an answer. On the site, it's preferred that "duplicate" questions be linked together, but the closest I could find is this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9852832/1191259

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
DT[!(var %like% 'expr')]
```

Information on other logical operators can be found on the same help page; type `` ?`!` `` in the console to open it.