# How to train several models within a loop for

Tags: r, for-loop, machine-learning, subset, r-caret

I want to train several models with `caret` package (one for each of the 7 response variables) **within a loop for**.

My data.frame `data` has 46 predictors (all of them are used to train all models) and 7 responses.

Some Rcode I tried but it failed:

```
models.list = list()
Ynames = names(data)[47:ncol(data)]
for(y in Ynames)
{
models.list[[y]] = train(as.name(y)~., subset(data,select=-Ynames[-y]),method="".....)
}
```

My variable `Ynames` contains all the responses. 
Each model must be trained with a single response variable. 
So for iteration 1, we would train the model for `Ynames[1]` response and all 46 predictors, but it's necessary to exclude from the dataset `data` all non-first response variables (`Ynames[-1]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an alternative which matches your example (using iris). The subsetting was based on this post: [removing a list of columns from a data.frame using subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845929/removing-a-list-of-columns-from-a-data-frame-using-subset)

```
models.list = list()
Ynames = names(iris)[3:ncol(iris)]

for(y in Ynames)
{
  to.remove <- Ynames[!Ynames==y]
  `%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
  models.list[[y]] = train(as.name(y)~., subset(iris,select = names(iris) %ni% to.remove),method="".....)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It doesn't work for me, I get the following error: "Error in model.frame.default(form = as.name(y) ~ ., data = subset(iris,  : 
  object is not a matrix"

Comment: Fixed if I modify the input formula: "train(as.formula(paste(y,"~.",sep="")), subset(iris,s...."

Comment: ah, did not check the actual train function but great!

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier if you avoid the formula class and use one matrix or data.frame for your responses and another for your predictors :

```
Y <- matrix(runif(700, 0, 100), ncol = 7)
X <- matrix(runif(4600, 0, 100), ncol = 46)
colnames(Y) <- paste("Y", 1:ncol(Y))
colnames(X) <- paste("X", 1:ncol(X))

library(caret)

models.list = as.list(vector(length = ncol(Y)))
for(i in 1:ncol(Y)) {
    models.list[[i]] <- train(x = X, y = Y[,i], method = "lm")
}
```